# I have added a parcel for spark 2.4 and created a service for spark 2. But its invoking spark 1.6 shell

Tags: installation, cloudera-cdh, apache-spark-2.3

In CDH 5.13, I have added a spark 2.4 parcel and created a spark 2 service in cloud manager. but when i am running spark2-shell, its invoking spark 1.6

CDH version: 5.13

```
spark 2 csd : /usr/lib/SPARK2-2.4.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.1041012
Conf : Java 1.8 (already present)
```

> [cloudera@quickstart lib]$ spark2-shell Setting default log level to
>   "WARN". To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). SLF4J:
>   Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings. SLF4J: Found binding in
>   [jar:file:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in
>   [jar:file:/usr/lib/flume-ng/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in
>   [jar:file:/usr/lib/parquet/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in
>   [jar:file:/usr/lib/avro/avro-tools-1.7.6-cdh5.13.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an
>   explanation. SLF4J: Actual binding is of type
>   [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory] Welcome to

---

/ **/** **_ _____/ /**
_\ / _ / _ `/ **/ '*/
/***/ .__/_,*/*/ /*/_\ version 1.6.0
/*/

> Using Scala version 2.10.5 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java
>   1.8.0_202) Type in expressions to have them evaluated. Type :help for more information. Spark context available as sc (master = local[*],
>   app id = local-1565015557669). SQL context available as sqlContext.

I expect it will invoke spark 2.4 shell, but its calling spark 1.6 shell.